# Multi-tiered list Formatting

Tags: r, pivot

I'm doing a Response API pull and get a multi-tiered list for the Income Statement.  I'm trying to format the data into a dataframe where the income statement rows become the columns and the fiscal periods become the rows.  When I execute the below code I almost get what I want but the first column, which contains the period, isn't actually a column.  With a bit of manipulation, I think I can get my desired outcome, but was hoping someone might have a more elegant solution to my problem.

```
library('httr')
library('tidyr')

 url4 <- "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/NKE/financials?frequency=1"
  
  response_fin_ann <- GET(url4, add_headers(`User-Agent`= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
                                           ,`Accept-Language`= "en-US,en;q=0.5")) 

api_con_fin_ann <- content(response_fin_ann)

api_con_ann_fmt<- tibble(asOf = api_con_fin_ann$data$incomeStatementTable$asOf) %>%
  reframe(rows = lapply(api_con_fin_ann$data$incomeStatementTable$rows, as.data.frame)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(rows)

cols<-api_con_fin_ann$data$incomeStatementTable$headers
colnames(api_con_ann_fmt) <- cols

tst3 <- as.data.frame(t(api_con_ann_fmt))
colnames(tst3) <- tst3[1,]
tst3<-tst3[-1, ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it elegant, but that `asOf` is empty for me, so no need to process that; data.frame construction can be left for `jsonlite` (through `content(..., simplifyVector = TRUE)`), and when going through `pivot_longer()` + `pivot_wider()`, we don't need to fiddle with column names like with transposed frame:

```r
library(httr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# complete response:
# url4 <- "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/NKE/financials?frequency=1"
# value5 is empty:
url4 <- "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/FOF/financials?frequency=1"
  
response_fin_ann <- GET(url4, add_headers(`User-Agent`= "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/119.0"
                                          ,`Accept-Language`= "en-US,en;q=0.5")) 

api_con_fin_ann <- content(response_fin_ann, simplifyVector = TRUE)$data$incomeStatementTable

# response for FOF includes an empty column:
str(api_con_fin_ann$headers)
#> List of 5
#>  $ value1: chr "Period Ending:"
#>  $ value2: chr "12/31/2008"
#>  $ value3: chr "12/31/2007"
#>  $ value4: chr "12/31/2006"
#>  $ value5: chr ""
head(api_con_fin_ann$rows, n = 3) 
#>            value1  value2  value3  value4 value5
#> 1   Total Revenue $19,105 $44,769 $10,272       
#> 2 Cost of Revenue  $3,563  $4,819    $468       
#> 3    Gross Profit $15,542 $39,951  $9,804

# switch names <-> values for select(..., all_of(cols)), drop empty values
(cols <- setNames(names(api_con_fin_ann$headers), api_con_fin_ann$headers)[api_con_fin_ann$headers != ""])
#> Period Ending:     12/31/2008     12/31/2007     12/31/2006 
#>       "value1"       "value2"       "value3"       "value4"

select(api_con_fin_ann$rows, all_of(cols)) |>
  pivot_longer(-1, names_to = "period") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = 1, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 20
#>   period   `Total Revenue` `Cost of Revenue` `Gross Profit` `Operating Expenses`
#>   <chr>    <chr>           <chr>             <chr>          <chr>               
#> 1 12/31/2… $19,105         $3,563            $15,542        ""                  
#> 2 12/31/2… $44,769         $4,819            $39,951        ""                  
#> 3 12/31/2… $10,272         $468              $9,804         ""                  
#> # ℹ 15 more variables: `Research and Development` <chr>,
#> #   `Sales, General and Admin.` <chr>, `Non-Recurring Items` <chr>,
#> #   `Other Operating Items` <chr>, `Operating Income` <chr>,
#> #   `Add'l income/expense items` <chr>,
#> #   `Earnings Before Interest and Tax` <chr>, `Interest Expense` <chr>,
#> #   `Earnings Before Tax` <chr>, `Income Tax` <chr>, `Minority Interest` <chr>,
#> #   `Equity Earnings/Loss Unconsolidated Subsidiary` <chr>, …
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: margusl, your solution worked brilliantly and was exactly what I was chasing.  Your solution was also much more elegant than the path I was headed down.  Thanks for taking the time to lend me a hand.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: margusl, thoughts on how to adjust the code for an example where one of the columns (value5) is null?  An example would be if you changed url4=https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/FOS/financials?frequency=1

Comment: @RDS , are you sure about that request? For me the response is: `{"data":null,"message":"Our data provider is not providing us with Annual data for FOS", ...}` .  Are you working with a list of companies?

Comment: my apologies.  Yes, you are correct, I am working with a list of companies.  I'm running this through a loop and solved the issue with a company (FOS) not having any financial data.  I meant to ask about url4="https://api.nasdaq.com/api/company/FOF/financials?frequency=1"  .  Value5 ends up with a blank period.  I played around with a few hours yesterday and couldn't quite get it.  Thanks again for the assistance!

Comment: Updated the answer to properly handle empty columns: only existing values will remain in `cols`  and replaced `rename()` with `select()`